# Php inserting values into multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Ok, I'm parsing a html file using simple_dom_html and everything works fine.
What I'm trying to do is to insert the values into a multi dimensional array.

Here's my code:

```
foreach ($html->find('li[class="searchFacetDimension"]') as $filtros) {
    foreach($filtros->find('div[class="dimensionContainer"] h4') as $titulo){
            echo $titulo->plaintext . "<br>";
        foreach($filtros->find('div[class="dimensionContainer"] ul li a') as $link){
            echo $link->plaintext . "<br>";
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

It outputs:

Category 1

- sub 1
- sub 2

Category 2

- sub 1

What I'm trying to do is output it as an array, something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cat] => Category 1
            [subs] => Sub 1, Sub 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cat] => Category 2
            [subs] => Sub 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you need:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($html->find('li[class="searchFacetDimension"]') as $filtros) {
    $aux = array()
    foreach($filtros->find('div[class="dimensionContainer"] h4') as $titulo){
            //echo $titulo->plaintext . "<br>";
            $aux['cat'] = $titulo->plaintext;
        foreach($filtros->find('div[class="dimensionContainer"] ul li a') as $link){
            //echo $link->plaintext . "<br>";
            $aux['subs'][] = $link->plaintext;
        }
        //echo "<br>";
    }
    $aux['subs'] = implode(", ",$aux['subs']);
    $result[] = $aux;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You did all the hard work. All you have to do is make an array:

```
$array = array();
foreach ($html->find('li[class="searchFacetDimension"]') as $filtros) {
    foreach($filtros->find('div[class="dimensionContainer"] h4') as $titulo){
            $array[] = array('cat'=>$titulo->plaintext,'subs'=>'');
        foreach($filtros->find('div[class="dimensionContainer"] ul li a') as $link){
            if($array[sizeof($array)-1]['subs'] != '')
                $array[sizeof($array)-1]['subs'].= ', ';
            $array[sizeof($array)-1]['subs'].= $link->plaintext;
        }
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

Note: I did add in a little complication about only using the comma separator when subs is not empty. I made it verbose to make it very clear that is what I was doing.

Comment: Hey kainaw thanks for your help, you code worked great but the other solution came out first. I just want to thank you anyway!